# ASP.NET Core - Visual Studio 2017 Publish setup

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, setup-project, msdeploy, publishing

[image]

Hi, can someone please list and explain all the most important PROS and CONS when choosing different Publish options:

- when using the first setup with **Deployment Mode:
  Framework-Dependent / Target runtime: Portable**
- when using the second setup with **Deployment Mode: Self-Contained / 
  Target Runtime: win-x64.**

Answer (score 0):

Framework-dependent deployments can be deployed to target machines where .NET Core is already installed. So your application doesn't have to deploy .NET Core with it.

Self-contained deployments deploys .NET Core with the application and requires no further .NET Core dependencies on the target machine.

For more information and pros and cons for both deployment models, see the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/